# Exchanging derivative and integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Define the function $g:[1,2]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be
$$
g(t):= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}4} \arctan\frac{\sin 2x}{t-2\sin^2 x}\,dx.
$$
I would like to differentiate obtaining
\begin{align*}
g'(t) &= \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}4} \arctan\frac{\sin 2x}{t-2\sin^2 x}\,dx 
=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}4} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\arctan\frac{\sin 2x}{t-2\sin^2 x}\right)\,dx=\\
&= -\int_0^{\frac{\pi}4} \frac{\sin 2x}{2(t-1)\cos 2x + t(t-2)+2} \,dx.
\end{align*}
and I would like to be sure to be allowed to do that.

Call $f(x,t)$ the integrand function, defined over $\left[0,\frac{\pi}4\right]\times [1,2]$. For all $t\in [1,2]$ we have $|f(x,t)|\leq \frac{\pi}2$, which is integrable over $\left[0,\frac{\pi}4\right]$, and for all $x\in \left[0,\frac{\pi}4\right]$ we have that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)$ exists and satisfies $\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)\right|\leq \sin 2x$, which again is summable over $\left[0,\frac{\pi}4\right]$.

> Are this domination conditions enough to be allowed to derive under
>   the integral sign?

Answer (score 4):

The conditions are sufficient to reach the conclusion.

With $\displaystyle f(x,t) = \arctan\frac{\sin 2x}{t-2\sin^2 x}$, we have $\displaystyle \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)\right| \leqslant \sin 2x$ for $x \in [0,\pi/4]$.

Thus, for any sequence $t_n \to t \in [1,2]$, it follows from the mean value theorem that there exists $\xi_{n,x}$ between $t$ and $t_n$ such that

$$\frac{g(t_n) - g(t)}{t_n - t} = \int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{f(x,t_n) - f(x,t)}{t_n - t} \, dx = \int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,\xi_{n,x}) \, dx $$

Since $\displaystyle \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,\xi_{n,x})\right| \leqslant \sin 2x$ (which is integrable), it follows by the dominated convergence theorem that

$$g'(t) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{f(x,t_n) - f(x,t)}{t_n - t} \, dx = \int_0^{\pi/4}\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(x,t_n) - f(x,t)}{t_n - t} \, dx =\\ \int_0^{\pi/4}\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t) \, dx$$

Comment: Thanks. A further question: in the last equality, don't you need $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ to be continuous at least in $t$? Indeed I found some results stating that, for the Riemann integral, the domination conditions above *and* the continuity of $f$ and its partial derivative are enough to yield the conclusion. Am I missing something?

Comment: @SoniaP: You're welcome. Actually all you need is that $x \mapsto f(x,t_0)$ is integrable for some $t_0 \in [c,d]$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ exists for all $(x,t) \in [a,b]\times[c,d]$, and the dominating condition $\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t) \right| \leqslant h(x)$ where $h$ is integrable on $[a,b]$.

Comment: The reason is $f(x,t) = f(x,t_0) + (t-t_0)\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,\xi)$ by the mean value theorem and, hence, $|f(x,t)| \leqslant |f(x,t_0)| + |t-t_0|h(x)$.  This shows that $x \mapsto f(x,t)$ is integrable over $[a,b]$ for every $t \in [c,d]$.

Comment: Basically the partial derivative is measurable as it is a limit of a sequence of measurable functions.  By the dominating condition it is integrable without the need for continuity.

Comment: For Riemann integrals it is enough that the partial derivative is continuous on $[a,b]\times [c,d]$ since everything is integrable.